# How to protect the route from curl in Express Node js?

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I have a route, for example `/data`, which brings data from php to nodejs using curl, but this route is also available from the client side, so I want to allow to use this route only for curl request. How do I can implement it ?

Comment: well technically you could check the user-agent, but an evil client could technically just fake their user-agent and use the route as well. perhaps you should consider an actual security concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, as HTTP is an open protocol and all client can be simulated.

However, a simple credential can be used to protect the resource, such as `/data?password=u8iK9oC` -- unless the password is correct, no `/data` resource would be returned to client. If only curl client know this password, the requirement is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Use an authentication or IP whitelist. Because any data in the request can be modificated.